What question do participles answer?
I read in a book by Stanley Fish that a sentence is a series of relationships, and one exercise that was recommended in the book for mastering sentence construction was building up a sentence by answering questions. This, to my mind, seemed a good way to compose sentences in general. But though I can understand what question each part of speech (along with the words chosen) answers, I do not understand what a participle answers, except causation and simultaneous action.
Since participles are mostly used to signify simultaneous action, I do not know how the writing of participles can result from answering questions, because, "What was the subject or object doing at the time of the action?" is a very broad question, and does not provide specific generative power for constructing a sentence.
My question therefore is this: What questions do participles answer? And, if I am to construct a sentence by answering questions, what question will lead me to the addition of a participle to the sentence? It would seem that this part of speech is based wholly on a propositional understanding of sentences, and not on an understanding having to do with a questions and answers.
I did not write this post by answering questions, but as I usually write posts.

Past participles often serve as adjectives, and Present / Continuous participles can also serve as nouns. But the question is far too broad - plus it looks like something that belongs on English Language Learners

What was the book? Doesn't it discuss the matter? Why is "What was the subject or object doing at the time of the action?" too vague? (Or more tersely "Whatcha doin'?") What sort of question is acceptably precise?

Participial clauses can answer the question "What circumstances attended this?"    "He opened the door of the mountain cabin, the blizzard swirling behind him."
